# Define a single C# method which accepts any object that can be used with square brackets

Tags: c#, methods, types

I'm implementing a method that, given some data retrieved via DataRowView or DbDataReader, hydrates a DTO.

So, both of the data sources implement the possibility to retrieve a particular field value through

```cs
public object this[string name] { get; }
```

But this behavior is not constrainted by a common interface between the two classes so I cannot use it, and have to write the hydration code twice without changing a single bit. Which is bad.

```cs
public MyDTO Hydrate(DataRowView data)
{
    MyDTO f_return = new MyDTO();
    f_return.Foo = (string)data["foo"];
    f_return.Bar = (uint)data["bar"];
    f_return.Baz = (DateTime)data["baz"];
    return f_return;
}

public MyDTO Hydrate(DbDataReader data)
{
    MyDTO f_return = new MyDTO();
    f_return.Foo = (string)data["foo"];
    f_return.Bar = (uint)data["bar"];
    f_return.Baz = (DateTime)data["baz"];
    return f_return;
}
```

Am I missing some C# syntax that would allow me to define a single method which constraints the input to any object that can be accessed via square brackets?

Something like this

```cs
public MyDTO Hydrate(object[string] data)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you can't refer to needed property directly in your `object data` variable?
I mean `data["YourPropery"]`.

Comment: A common alternative to "this object should do X" when you can't retrofit types or interfaces is to allow the caller to pass in a delegate that does the required thing (in this case a `Func<T, string, TResult>`, i.e. `Func<Foo, string, object> x = (foo, name) => foo[name];`). This makes for slightly clumsy invocation, but still allows you to reuse most of the code (and you can paper over it with reflection for the really common cases, i.e. "find the indexer that takes a `string` and make a delegate out of it").

Comment: @StanislavBalia because I'm already doing it, twice. One for DataRowView and one for DbDataReader. And that's what i would like to avoid.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I would have to do it for every field anyway, and considering that most of the assignation code is quite simple and I'm working on several records, delegates would be a unuseful overhead most of the time

Comment: If you're concerned with overhead, though, you probably shouldn't be using `DataRowView` or anything else related to `DataTable` -- these things have poor performance characteristics. (Unboxing `object`s everywhere is no picnic either!) For mapping `DataReader`s, there are *many* fast alternatives, like Dapper, or hand-written access with FastMember (the latter is an option for the more general case too, incidentally) -- reinventing the wheel there isn't useful.

Comment: @JeroenMostert the overhead in the code is low enough for my project needs. As I was saying in another comment, this hydration code is auto-generated so it's not a big deal (most of the time, except for some custom DTOs). Reinventing the wheel isn't useful for sure, but I needed something between Dapper and NHibernate and nothing fit my needs more than my own wrapper (that it's not the fastest for sure).

Comment: That's fine, but then there's no need to worry about "overhead" from a delegate call either -- I doubt you'd even be able to measure that. You could even make the parameter `dynamic` and probably still not notice a problem. (This would not get you compile-time safety, of course; you could pass any old type whether it had an indexer or not. But it's a very quick way to get things working.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I missing some C# syntax that would allow me to define a single method which constraints the input to any object that can be accessed via square brackets?

No; there's no C# syntax for expressing "something that is indexable", other than creating an `interface` with that indexer, i.e.

```cs
interface ISomeInterface {
    object this[string name] {get;}
}
```

and limiting yourself to instances of `ISomeInterface`, or some generic `<T>` with the `where T : ISomeInterface` constraint.

Comment: But I cannot inject an interface on a code that it's not written by me. So it unfortunately doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: @lukenpi  Your constraints are unrealisable without extra plumbing and you may need to rethink your design

Comment: I need to have the ability to hydrate from both sources. Considered that this hydration code is auto-generated is not a big deal, but was wondering if there was a better solution than writing the code twice.

Comment: @lukenpi well... you could use `dynamic`, but... that's not a *good* solution